# Auto-complete suggestion for email id while typing email id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Friends 
 I want to use automatic suggestion for typing email-id.
 I am thinking that it should appear as soon as user type in the uitextfield.

Their is one NSMutableArray which will contain all email-ids.
 when user type in uitextfield the id which matches in the array should appear.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) the good tutorial for your question...

Comment: Thanx its a good suggestion.But can we do it as "auto gramatical correction" appears in iphone

Comment: if you make new question then other may help you too !